# Issues with Ionic Native in multi-platoform app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

I'm creating an app with Ionic 2 that runs as a website in a browser and as an app on iOS and Android. It uses the [SQLite](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/sqlite/) plugin when on mobile devices. The issue I'm having is the SQLite plugin has to import ionic-native stuff, which when running as a website throws an error because ionic-native is only on cordova devices. How do I get around this?

The import that is causing the error:

`import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';`

and the error that is thrown:

`Cannot find module "@ionic-native/core"`

Comment: import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from 'ionic-native';

Answer (score 2):

Opps. I thought it was because ionic-native wasn't being included in my non-cordova platform. But I just needed to install the core package with `npm install @ionic-native/core --save`

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error, but with a different module(InAppBrowser).
This code solved it for me.

in app.module.ts add:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';    

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
 ...
 ]
 providers: [
 ...
 InAppBrowser,
 ...
 ],
```

and .ts file i use this:

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}
```